# iPhone push notification unable in reading notification

Tags: apple-push-notifications

The apple device showing me notification but when i open it , its batch number does not gets clear from device please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;` in your `UIApplicationDelegate.didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or `UIApplicationDelegate.didReceiveRemoteNotification`.

If you need reset application icon badge number from server, set `badge` value to 0 in APN message.